# Matrix defined with arraylist of objects in each cell

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I want to implement in Java a map with defined dimensions and in each zone there could be 0 or many objects.

Example of non-functional code:

```
int[][] map = new int[10][10];
map[1][2] = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Graphical idea "three-dimensional histogram".

It is somehow possible to create a matrix (Lists, ArrayLists) with limited dimensions on the X and Y axis but unlimited on the Z axis with the methods of an ArrayList.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the code to create a limited matrix in X and Y but use ArrayList of objects in Z

Comment: What does that mean `limited dimensions on the X and Y` and  `but unlimited on the Z`? Maybe you can start with modeling a 3-D point as a **class** with a method that makes sense in your problem domain? You have to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of objects.

```java
ArrayList<T>[][] map = new ArrayList<>[10][10];
map[1][2] = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is not a easy go-to answer for something like this. One option would be a `Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, List<T>>` for a sparse map, but you may need to enforce your own limits on the dimensions.